# R, for loop with ifelse and grepl function does not give expected results

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, grepl

I'm trying to find matching string with my_list and data frame(df) and depending on TRUE/FALSE I need to populate  new_name column in df with first sting in matching list (my_list[[i]][1]) in case TRUE , or "cat" column value in case no match.

My data frame is as follows:

```
name <- c("NETFLIX.COM", "BlueTV", "smv", "trafi", "alkatel")
cat<- c("none", "none", "none", "transportation", "communication")
df<-data.frame(name, cat)
```

My list:

```
travel<- c("travel","air_com", "AIRCAT", "tivago")
leasure<- c("leasure","MTV", "NETFLIX.COM")
my_list<- list(travel, leasure)
```

My for loop with ifelse and grepl is as follows:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
      for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
        df[j, "new_name"]<- ifelse( 
        grepl(paste(my_list[[i]], collapse="|"), tolower(df[j, "name"])),
          my_list[[i]][1], 
          df[j, "cat"])
```

Expected output is :

```
df["new_name"]<- c("leasure", "none", "none", "transportation", "communication")
df

name            cat       new_name
1 NETFLIX.COM           none        leasure
2      BlueTV           none           none
3         smv           none           none
4       trafi transportation transportation
5     alkatel  communication  communication
```

Currently with the for loop I wrote I obtain exact copy of "cat" column meaning that all cases are considered as nonmatching (FALSE) in ifelse function. I'm note sure what's wrong here...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `ifelse()` in that loop.  Use an `if` statement for flow control.  `ifelse()` is used for a vectorized selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to use `ifelse()` in that context:  it is for vectorized selection.  But your code would work if you had the pattern matching right.  Unfortunately, for `j == 1` and `i == 2` (when you expected a match), your pattern is

```
"leasure|MTV|NETFLIX.COM"
```

and you are trying to match it to `tolower(df[j, "name"])`, which is

```
"netflix.com"
```

You should map both strings to lowercase, or set `ignore.case = TRUE` in the `grepl()` call.  For example,

```r
name <- c("NETFLIX.COM", "BlueTV", "smv", "trafi", "alkatel")
cat<- c("none", "none", "none", "transportation", "communication")
df<-data.frame(name, cat)

travel<- c("travel","air_com", "AIRCAT", "tivago")
leasure<- c("leasure","MTV", "NETFLIX.COM")
my_list<- list(travel, leasure)

for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    df[j, "new_name"] <- 
      if( grepl(paste(my_list[[i]], collapse="|"), df[j, "name"],
            ignore.case = TRUE))
        my_list[[i]][1] 
      else df[j, "cat"]
  }
}
df
#>          name            cat       new_name
#> 1 NETFLIX.COM           none        leasure
#> 2      BlueTV           none           none
#> 3         smv           none           none
#> 4       trafi transportation transportation
#> 5     alkatel  communication  communication
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Generally speaking using pattern matching to find if a string is in a list is tricky; be really careful that your strings in `my_list` never include any characters that `grepl()` treats as special in a regular expression.  For your example you'll get the same result as the `grepl()` gives using the test

```
tolower(df[j, "name"]) %in% tolower(my_list[[i]])
```

but that's not true for all possible `name` values:  the `grepl()` code will allow partial matches (e.g. `df[i, "name"]` equal to  `"netflix.com in a long string"`) and `%in%` won't.

Comment: Thanks, your code works perfectly in R. But now (and may be this has to be separate question) I have similar problem in RShiny . The new column "cat_new" doesn't contain "leasure" category. I think this is related to shiny (DT::datatable(df)), but wonder how I can fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `stringr::str_replace_all` -

```
travel<- c("travel","air_com", "AIRCAT", "tivago")
leasure<- c("leasure","MTV", "NETFLIX.COM")
#Create a named list
my_list<- dplyr::lst(travel, leasure)


result <- stringr::str_replace_all(df$name, setNames(names(my_list), 
          sapply(my_list, paste0, collapse = '|')))

#If the result is same as original value keep the previous cat.
df$new_name <- ifelse(result == df$name, df$cat, result)
df

#         name            cat       new_name
#1 NETFLIX.COM           none        leasure
#2      BlueTV           none           none
#3         smv           none           none
#4       trafi transportation transportation
#5     alkatel  communication  communication
```

Here the important part is this code -

```
setNames(names(my_list), sapply(my_list, paste0, collapse = '|'))

#travel|air_com|AIRCAT|tivago      leasure|MTV|NETFLIX.COM 
#                    "travel"                    "leasure"
```

This means that whenever the pattern `travel|air_com|AIRCAT|tivago` is encountered in the string it will return `"travel"` as output and same for `"leasure"`.